gitlab pipeline getting jobs:backup config key may not be used with `rules`: only
This is my gitlab pipeline setup. I have a deploy task that deploys the code and backup task that backups the database. But I keep getting this error:

jobs:backup config key may not be used with rules: only

There are two pipelines. I want to run backup IF the branch is master and WHATEVER environment variable is present. Similarly, I want to run deploy if the branch is master and WHATEVER environment variable is not present.
I am struggling with this. Appreciate any help or hint.
.gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - local: "ci/backup.gitlab-ci.yml"
  - local: "ci/deploy.gitlab-ci.yml"

stages:
  - deploy
  - backup

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    - if: "$WHATEVER"
      when: never
  script:
    - echo "Running build"

backup:
  stage: backup
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    - if: "$WHATEVER"
  script:
    - echo "Running backup"

backup.gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:latest
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: docker

variables:
  HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_TOKEN
  APP_NAME: "milwaukee-internationals-core"
  HEROKU_EMAIL: "whatever"
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  BUCKET_NAME: milwaukee-internationals-backup

backup:
  stage: backup
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  resource_group: heroku
  only:
    - master
  allow_failure: false
  before_script:
    - export CI_JOB_TIMESTAMP=$(date --utc -Iseconds)
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
  script:
    - heroku login
    - export PRESIGNED_URL=$(aws s3 presign s3://$BUCKET_NAME/$CI_JOB_TIMESTAMP --expires-in 3600)
    - heroku pg:backups:capture --app $APP_NAME
    - heroku pg:backups:url --app $APP_NAME | xargs -I{} wget -O "$CI_JOB_TIMESTAMP.dump" "{}"
    - wget --method=PUT --body-file="$CI_JOB_TIMESTAMP.dump" $PRESIGNED_URL --header="Content-Type: application/octet-stream"

deploy.gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:latest
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: docker

variables:
  HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_TOKEN
  APP_NAME: "milwaukee-internationals-core"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  HEROKU_REGISTRY: "registry.heroku.com"
  HEROKU_EMAIL: "whatever"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  resource_group: heroku
  only:
    - master
  allow_failure: false
  before_script:
    - apk --no-cache add curl nodejs npm
    - npm install -g heroku
  script:
    - heroku container:login
    - heroku container:push --app $APP_NAME web
    - heroku container:release --app $APP_NAME web


ONly is deprecated in place of rules: if now. Your CI wont allow you to define a rules key and a only key in the same job
